# JBoss Forge new Gradle Project?

Tags: jboss, gradle

When starting a new project using JBoss Forge, the project is creating with a Maven build system by default.  How do I take advantage of Forge 2.*'s Gradle AddOn to create the project using Gradle instead of Maven?

```
% forge
Using Forge at /usr/local/Cellar/jboss-forge/2.12.2.Final/libexec

…

[ForgePlaygroundGradle]$ new-project --name ForgePlaygroundGradle --topLevelPackage com.kedges.forgegradle --porjectFolder . **???**;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here are two things:

1) After you start Forge, make sure you have installed the Gradle addon (it does not come with the core distribution):

```
addon-install --coordinate org.jboss.forge.addon:gradle,2.12.2.Final
```

2) Then you can use the `--buildSystem` option of the `project-new` command:

```
project-new --named ForgePlaygroundGradle --topLevelPackage com.kedges.forgegradle
```

Please note that the latter command may take some time to execute the first time. The reason for this is the downloading of the dependencies for a decent Java EE web project. Same happens with Maven projects when you create them with an empty local ~/.m2/repository folder.

If you don't need a web project, then consider the other project types provided by the `--type` option.

Comment: I try to use the current Gradle addon (V2.12.2) with my current forge installation (V2.19) and I get an exception `Facet type [org.jboss.forge.addon.gradle.projects.facets.GradleJavaCompilerFacet] could not be installed into [org.jboss.forge.addon.gradle.projects.GradleProject@d9a3733b] of type [org.jboss.forge.addon.gradle.projects.GradleProject]. You may wish to check for inconsistent origin state as partial installation may have occurred.` - could it be that those two version are not compatible?

Comment: Just tried installing Gradle addon version 2.12.2 in Forge 2.20.1. The installation was successful. I would recommend that you download the latest version from [the official location](http://forge.jboss.org/download) and try with it.